# Python generated wav file leads to "unidentified developer" warning

Tags: python, wav, quicktime

There are a lot of questions about how applications can be flagged with the "com.apple.quarantine" attribute, which causes the popup warning that says "*...can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.*" However, I'm having this problem with individual files that I create.

I was creating wav files with Python using the [wave](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module. I made a "test.wav" and it played just fine at first with iTunes by typing "open test.wav" in the terminal. But then I made QuickTime the default player for .wav files, and now I run into the "unidentified developer" issue everytime I try to open my test.wav file. I can easily use xattr to remove it, but it just comes back the next time I open it or modify it.

I intend to create lots of wav files, so I don't want to have to remove the attribute over and over.

I don't fully understand what is causing the attribute to be there in the first place, but is there something I can do when creating a file that will avoid this problem?

Comment: Did you try [other Python libraries for writing WAV files](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/index.ipynb)?